# Checkbox android not working

Tags: android, android-checkbox

Textview should be made visible on checking the checkbox. However, it's not happening. When i tap on the checkbox, it becomes checked but the texview doesn't appear. i've set the visibility of the textview to be GONE in the XML. However,i'm setting it to VISIBLE when the checkbox is checked.

```
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, viewGroup,
                    false);


   final CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) footer.findViewById(R.id.notify_confirm);
                final TextView notify_tv = (TextView) footer.findViewById(R.id.notify_tv);



                chb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                if (chb.isChecked()) 
                {
                    //new CheckBoxThread().execute();
                      notify_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    

                }
                else 
                {

                }

              }

            });
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingLeft="6dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                  android:background="#ffffff"
         >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"

       >

         <CheckBox
             android:id="@+id/notify_confirm"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:text="Notify on Confirmation"
             android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
             android:paddingLeft="5dp"
             android:visibility="visible"

             />
         <TextView
             android:id = "@+id/notify_tv"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:textColor = "@color/myPrimaryColor"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:visibility="gone"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:text="You will be notified on confirmation"></TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It might be a bit naive of me to ask this question but i've tried everything and it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use `OnCheckedChangeListener` for `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `OnClickListener` , use `OnCheckedChangeListener` for checkboxes. Replace your code as below.

```
chb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
            notify_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this property to the checkbox widget android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>

Within the Activity that hosts this layout, the following method handles the click event for both checkboxes:

public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.notify_confirm:
            if (checked)
                //visible the textview here
            else
                //
            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your way with onClickListener:

```
chkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkIos checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
               "Bro, try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
else{
//do else work
}

      }
    });
```

Other and Better way is to use:

```
 CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener:
```

As described by Mr. Lal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code it was fine, but just a little bit orientation (Layout Orientation) problem was there.
and Don't use TextView:visibility:"gone" (as gone will update your view and your view will scattered) rather use "invisible", it will not effect your view.

just put android:orientation="vertical" on your second LinearLayout.

here is your modified Layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/notify_confirm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Notify on Confirmation"
            android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notify_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="You will be notified on confirmation"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:visibility="invisible" >
        </TextView>      
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is your java file:

```
final CheckBox chb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.notify_confirm);
final TextView notify_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notify_tv);
      chb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chb.isChecked()) 
            {
                //new CheckBoxThread().execute();
                  notify_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
            }
            else 
            {
                 notify_tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
            }
          }
        });
```

this will work... :)